# Bootstrap nested rows

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to replicate this picture with bootstrap but I'm struggling with the nested row.

Here is the link to the final image how it should be:

https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/1*2H0HPHmFNs2t78Zog8kd9w.png

Basically I can't figure out how to put the orange next to the watermelon.

Here is my code but I'm a bit far:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="mirtilli.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="fragole.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="/anguria.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="/arance.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="/papaya.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="/ananas.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replicate this screenshot of what the final state should be:

https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/1*2H0HPHmFNs2t78Zog8kd9w.png

But I get this instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `row` for creating a new row and columns with the appropriate values, please go through the below example and let me know if any doubts!

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x1200">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x1200">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
          <div class="col-12">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x1200">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x1840">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```